# Instanceof and type assertion

Tags: typescript

In typescript if I have the following class:

```
class Hello{
  public world: string;
}
```

Why is it when I type assert parsed json as `Hello`, `instanceof` returns false?

```
var json: string = `{"world": "world"}`;
var assertedJson: Hello = JSON.parse(json) as Hello;
var hello: Hello = new Hello();

console.log(assertedJson instanceof Hello); <!-- returns false
console.log(hello instanceof Hello); <!-- returns true (as expected)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `instanceof`is transpiled 'as is' to JavaScript. If you transpile your code you get:

```js
var Hello = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Hello() {
    }
    return Hello;
}());
var json = "{\"world\": \"world\"}";
var assertedJson = JSON.parse(json);
var hello = new Hello();
console.log(assertedJson instanceof Hello);
console.log(hello instanceof Hello);
```

`a instanceof b` checks that the prototype of b is in the prototype chain of a. Your `assertedJson` does not fulfills this requisite.

And the `as` operator means nothing when transpiled, is just an annotation

Comment: *"prototype of b is in the prototype chain of a"* - Do you have a link that I can read about this? - I don't really understand.

Comment: The MDN is the best place: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the type cast you do with `as` has no effect on the runtime. But, as a workaround, you can manually set the prototype of the parsed object so that it will be an instance of `Hello`, if you so desire:

```
class Hello {
    public world: string;
    public sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello", this.world);
    }    
}

var json: string = `{"world": "world"}`;
var assertedJson: Hello = JSON.parse(json) as Hello;
var hello: Hello = new Hello();

console.log(assertedJson instanceof Hello); // <!-- returns false
console.log(hello instanceof Hello); // <!-- returns true (as expected)

// Manual fix:
Object.setPrototypeOf(assertedJson, Hello.prototype);
console.log(assertedJson instanceof Hello); // <!-- returns true

// And doing so will then allow you to access the Hello methods too:
assertedJson.sayHello() // Prints "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Type assertion is for compiler at compile-time only, it does not have any effect at runtime. It's developer's responsibility to make sure that compile-time type assertion matches runtime behavior.

`instanceof` is run-time check, basically checking that the object was created using particular class constructor. It's not of much use for JSON objects, because these are created as instances of built-in `Object` type.

The answer from TypeScript developers about supporting run-time type checking consistent with type system is:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2444#issuecomment-85097544

> This has been suggested and discussed many times. We're always trying
>   to avoid pushing the type system into the runtime and the number of
>   types this actually works for (pretty much just classes and
>   primitives) isn't large enough to justify the complexity versus the
>   use cases it enables.

Comment: *"checking that the object was created using particular class constructor"* - do you know how this is actually done, that's pretty interesting.

Comment: it's explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), it checks for `constructor` property in the prototype chain.

Comment: and prototype chain is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)